# xamarin forms: adding fragment to xaml

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the pattern presented in this article  [tute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml) to add a native android fragment to the UI in a Xamarin Forms project.

The layout container used to host the fragment shows up on screen no problem but not the fragment components. The resulting view hierarchy as seen in the Android project shows the fragment embedded, but it appears nothing is actually rendered.

Some code:

```
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Util;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Xamarin.Forms;


    namespace NativeFeatures.Droid
    {

        public class TestNativeFragmentViewGroup : ViewGroup
        {
            Context context = Forms.Context;  // Android.App.Application.Context; // this is supposed to be the equivalent replacement but a crash occurs
            Android.Widget.Button buttonTest;

            public TestNativeFragmentViewGroup() : base(Forms.Context)
            {
                context = Forms.Context;  // ? Android.App.Application.Context; 

                this.Id = 43434;

                int minWidth = 300;
                int minHeight = 800;

                SetMinimumHeight(minHeight);
                SetMinimumWidth(minWidth);

                SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Firebrick);

                buttonTest = new Android.Widget.Button(context);
                buttonTest.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                buttonTest.SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(Android.Graphics.Color.ForestGreen));
                buttonTest.BringToFront();
                buttonTest.Text = "Button Test";
                buttonTest.Id = 12347;
                AddView(buttonTest); // this works

                addTestFragment(); // layout appears to be there but no fragment

            }

        LinearLayout ll = null;
            private void addTestFragment()
            {
                ll = new LinearLayout(context);
                ll.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent);
                ll.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                ll.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);

                ll.Id = 234567;

                ((Activity)context).FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(ll.Id, TestFragment.newInstance("I am frag 1"), "someTag1").Commit();
                ((Activity)context).FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(ll.Id, TestFragment.newInstance("I am frag 2"), "someTag2").Commit();


                AddView(ll);
            }


            protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {

                if (buttonTest != null)
                {
                    buttonTest.Layout(left, top, (right - left) / 5, (bottom - top) / 5);
                }

                if (ll != null)
                {
                    ll.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
                }


            }

            void UpdateUi()
            {
            }

        }
        public class TestFragment : Fragment
        {

            public static TestFragment newInstance(String text)
            {

                TestFragment f = new TestFragment();

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.PutString("text", text);
                f.Arguments = b;
                return f;
            }

            // @Override
            public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                Android.Views.View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, container, false);

                string val = Arguments.GetString("text");
                ((TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvFragText)).SetText(val.ToCharArray(), 0, val.Length);
                return v;
            }
        }


    }
```

and the AndroidView.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
                xmlns:formsandroid="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
                xmlns:NativeFeatures="clr-namespace:NativeFeatures.Droid;assembly=NativeFeatures.Android;targetPlatform=Android" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="NativeFeatures.AndroidView">
      <ContentView.Content>
          <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms Should just be Android Content!" />
                <NativeFeatures:TestNativeFragmentViewGroup/>
            </StackLayout>
      </ContentView.Content>
```

Am I missing something ?
Or does xamarin not support native fragments in this way ?

Comment: I am not sure why do you need fragments here? What is this particular scenario that cannot be handled in XF directly which is making you choose this route, please add more details like that. We might have a better solution altogether for you!

Comment: Ok so the ultimate aim is to use a third party fragment, specifically the Here Maps SDK. The Xamarin binding of the .aar file has been successful. I can get the map control on screen by adding the fragment to the root view in the Android project. This is unsatisfactory because (as expected) the fragment obscures any UI components passed down in the Xamarin library, or if I bring the Xamarin components forward (using BringToFront() on one of it's Layouts) then the Map Fragment does not get gestures as they are absorbed by the Xamarin project UI.

Comment: Should clarify that Here Maps provide Android and iOS libraries at this time but nothing to support Xamarin directly.

Comment: The article you link to includes a downloadable sample. Have you downloaded that sample, and successfully built and run it?

Comment: So why not just pass the control to the Android project i.e. navigate to android and then come back to XF once you are done with the native thing https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39924/navigating-from-android-activity-back-to-forms

Comment: @DSlaney According to your description, you want to add android view to Forms, there is fragment in android view, this fragment is not visible, and other control can display? Do you try to show Android view in Android, see wheather the UI can display correctly?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, I have built and run it, and the code I have presented is based on that sample program - but the sample adds custom views - doesn't involve fragments. I am possibly doing something wrong - like I say above - can see on screen the container layout I have attached the fragment to, but the actual fragment contents are not shown.

Comment: @FreakyAli So the idea is to mix ui specified in the xaml and native Android UI (the Here maps control). We want to do this in iOS as well.  That's what the sample tute is all about. So for example we will have menu bars and popup dialogs which will popup over the map, but we will write those once using xaml/C# in the Xamarin project, and use them in Android, iOS apps with the Here maps control being a native component.

Comment: @Cherry Bu Yes the binding of the .aar library from Here Maps was successful and in the Android project I can add the map to screen - but it will block the UI provided through the xaml in the Xamarin project - really need them in a say Grid layout superimposed. The Map is at Z order 0, and the xaml components overlay the map. It would be an elegant solution to have them all in the Xamarin project xaml, as the example tute program achieves with some views and Android Widgets - I just can't get it working with a fragment.

Comment: @DSlaney Anything update?

Comment: @CherryBu No, unfortunately. I will revisit some time soon but for now I have moved on to binding the iOS Framework. The Binding of the iOS Here SDK has been kinda painful but it looks like I will have more luck in embedding the iOS Here Map in the Forms project xaml.